# Is there any method by which I can recover my MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I had a Database in my localhost. After another developer uninstalled the XAMPP from my mac, I have re-installed it but the my database seems to be corrupted. Is there any way I can recover my database? Whenever I click any one of the tables of my databse it says "#1932- Table "database.table_name" doesn't exist in the engine".

[image: localhost image]

I have already tried some other solutions like where they say the ibdata1 file is missing. But I already have that file. What can I do now? In mac I couldn't find my backup files as this is a new installation. I only have that previous .sql file of my database but it says it is not in the engine.

Comment: You can learn that, for next time, it's important to create a backup.

Comment: What client application are you using on the Mac?  Can the client connect to the database server?

Comment: Assuming the innodb_file_per_table setting was enabled in the prev database (i) you'll need *.frm and *.ibd files for each table (ii) a `create table` statement for each table. Do you have both?

Comment: @SPlatten The database was used for my android app. Suddenly another developer created a same named database and it was overwritten. Now I have a backup file very old which is currently under my XAMPP folder. And I have no idea if I can revert my cpanel database to it's older version.

Comment: Also, in my XAMPP folder I have some files which is named after my Database's tables. Some .frm and .ibd files.

Comment: @Mostainahmed, can you remotely attach to the database using a PC and some SQL compatible client like HeidiSQL ?